# Unit Testing Similar Functions

Tags: java, unit-testing

I have setter functions that check their input data by passing it to a validation function before changing private variables. If the data is invalid, the getter functions throw an exception. How can I unit the setter functions and the data validation functions without repeating all of my input test cases for each of them? Both functions validate the data in the same way.

EDIT: Sorry, I should have included code to begin with.

```
setterFunction(String value) {
    if (valueValid()) {
        // Update member variable
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Invalid Data");
    }
}
```

Both valueValid() and setterFunction fail on the same values, so I don't want to have duplicate test code.

Comment: Post your setter, validation and getter methods.  It's very hard to get a context of what you're talking about without having code to refer to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be wise to test the validator with all test cases, and then test that the setter and getter call the validator correctly using a simple case or two.

This way if something fails - you also have a better understanding of where the bug is (the validator or setters/getters)

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but I was unsure if there was a better way that I didn't know of.

Comment: Well, I don't think there is much more to it - there is no duplicate test code this way and the smaller component is tested separately. I think that would be best practice and your common sense did not let you down.

Answer (score 0):

You could design your objects differently as well. Have your object define a constructor that requires a mimimal subset of information to properly construct an object.  Then have another method repInvariant() ([Liskov](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201657686)) that will validate that all the internal variables within the object are acceptible in combination.

Then if you do have a setter, it can simply call repInvariant() after setting the variable.  Perhaps even undoing the set method call.

```
  public class A 
    public A(B b, Cc...) {
      this.b = b;
      ...
      this.repInvariant();
    }
    public void setB(B b) {
       var oldB = this.b;
       try {
         this.b = b;
         this.repInvariant();
       } catch (InvalidArgumentException e) {
         this.b = oldB;
         throw e;
       }
    }
    public void repInvariant() {
       if (this.b == null) {
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("B must not be null");
       } 
    }
  }
```